# FinancialDerivative function call without parameter fails in Mathematica 10

Tags: functions, bugs

**fixed in 10.0.2**

---

When I type `FinancialDerivative[]` in *Mathematica* 10. There is error listed as follows.

Anybody know how to solve it?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Same for me, and it looks like a bug.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialDerivative.html?q=FinancialDerivative) `FinancialDerivative[]` is supposed to give a list of all available contract types. I get the same buggy output.

Comment: I get the same in 10.0.1 on OS X 10.10 -- definitely a bug

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Version 10.0.2. On windows:

```
  FinancialDerivative[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]